# ExpandableListView with custom controls in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am working on a application which is having a tree structure of books, I am displaying Book names in the Side Navigation menu with Expandable Listview, On clicking book name it is displaying the chapters in child list. But, in my case i need this in a different way, when User clicks on the Book Name it should open the ChaptersFragment and display the list of chapters there, and when user clicks on the expand icon, the chapters should display in Expandable List.

```
mDrawerListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    mDrawerListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    mDrawerListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {


        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    mDrawerListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback to the Activity, that says what item was clicked. Then the activity need to get the information to populate a new Fragment and use the FragmentManager to swap the new Fragment in.

In the NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
private NavigationDrawerListener mCallback;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.OnAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (NavigationDrawerListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("...");
    }
    ...
}
...
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        mCallback.onNavigationItemClicked(groupPosition);
    }
...
public static interface NavigationDrawerListerner {
    public void onNavigationItemClicked(int groupPosition)
}
...
```

In the Activity

```
...
@Override
public void onNavigationItemClicked(int groupPosition) {
    Bundle args = getFragmentInformation(); //somehow
    Fragment newFragment = YourFragment.newInstance(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            .replace(R.id.your_container), newFragment) //whatever ViewGroup contains the fragment
            .commit();
}
...
```

Comment: thanks @seiterm, but i need both the actions to perform.. I mean, wen user clicks on the indicator, it should expand the list.. How can we achieve this

Comment: Expanding the list is the default behavior. I assume this is working when the listener is not present.  Have you tried not consuming the event (returning false)?